# URL Parameters in JavaScript Not Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a URL parameter on one page and then read it back on the other page using JavaScript. Everything works beautifully until I realized that once a term is used, the same page won't update to the current code used in the page from the editor. For example, I used the term "dog" when I hadn't added any UI to the page. After adding some UI, I used the same term and nothing had updated. Then I tried another, random term and it showed up with the UI.

Here is the code on the first page, which directs to the search page:

```
function submitSearch(){
  var trm = document.getElementById("searchFld").value.toLowerCase();
  window.location = '/search.html?term='+trm;
}
```

Here is the code on the second page (The function load is called `onload` by the body):

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

function load(){
var trm = getUrlParameter('term');

document.title = 'Search for "' + trm + '"';
}
```

Hope I've been clear enough in explanation... Thanks!

Comment: I undeleted my answer. Did it work with `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: Please see my comment under your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function load(){
var trm = getParameterByName('term');
document.title = 'Search for "' + trm + '"';
}

window.onload = function() {
  load();
};
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) of the code for getting parameters.

Comment: It worked for it once, and then didn't do it again. I'm wondering it only updates every 30 minutes or something?? I need to do it immediately, though... :/

Comment: Same problem still